# Three elementary number sequences

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Three closely related number sequences go:

- $63, 37, 22, 39, 92, 26, 8, ?$
- $13, 11, 66, 9, 31, 1, 36, ?$
- $30, 54, 6, 23, 4, 7, ?$

All these sequences are really elementary.

**What number comes next in each sequence? And what is missing?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the next number in the three sequences, and what is missing are:

> 15, 3 and 12 and missing are corresponding numbers for Q, W and J

The sequences are numbers which represent the

> Atomic numbers of the chemical elements which have the same first letter as the three rows of a Qwerty keyboard and are the  first appearance of these letters in the ordered list of elements.
>
>
>  63 = Europium, 37 = Rubidium, 22 = Titanium, 39 = Yttrium, 92 = Uranium, 26 = Iron, 8 = Oxygen, **?** = **15** = **P**hosphorus
>
>
>  13 = Aluminum, 11 = Sodium, 66 = Dysprosium, 9 = Fluorine, 31 = Gallium, 1 = Hydrogen, 36 = Krypton, **?** = **3** = **L**ithium
>
>  30 = Zinc, 54 = Xenon, 6 = Carbon, 23 = Vanadium, 4 = Beryllium, 7 = Nitrogen, **?** = **12** = **M**agnesium
>
>  There are no chemical elements initially Q, W and J so these are missing.